# The operand data type "text" is invalid for the "max" operator

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT JobID, MAX(DispoInfo1), MAX(DispoInfo5), MAX(DispoInf10)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT RowID AS JobID, FieldName, FieldValue
        FROM FurtherInfo
        WHERE FieldName IN ('DispoInfo1', 'DispoInfo5', 'DispoInf10')
    ) s
    pivot
    (
      MAX(FieldValue)
      FOR FieldName IN (DispoInfo1, DispoInfo5, DispoInf10)
    ) piv
```

Why we cannot do the max(text datatype value) but we can perform max(nvarchar) in SQL?

Comment: where FieldValue is data type "text", 
it works fine when its datatype is "nvarchar"

Comment: Because `text` has been deprecated for more than a decade and you should have already replaced its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT JobID, MAX(DispoInfo1), MAX(DispoInfo5), MAX(DispoInf10)
FROM
(
    SELECT RowID AS JobID, FieldName,
```

> **CAST(FieldValue AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS FieldValue**

```
    FROM FurtherInfo
    WHERE FieldName IN ('DispoInfo1', 'DispoInfo5', 'DispoInf10')
) s
pivot
(
  MAX(FieldValue)
  FOR FieldName IN (DispoInfo1, DispoInfo5, DispoInf10)
) piv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use text field inside max by converting text field to varchar(max)/nvarchar(max)

```
MAX (CONVERT (varchar(max), fieldvalue ))
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the CONVERT keyword.

Comment: In the following query i am converting text to varchar and getting its max 
   SELECT Max(CONVERT (VARCHAR(max), de)) 
FROM   (SELECT CONVERT (TEXT, 'kjsfhdjkhsdakldfkjsdaklfklsdjklsfdajljkljdsfl')AS 
               de 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT CONVERT (TEXT, 'kjsfhdjkhsdakldfkjsdaklfklsdjklsfdajljkljdsfl')AS 
               de 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT CONVERT (TEXT, 'kjsfhdjkhsdakldfkjsdaklfklsdjklsfdajljkljdsfl')AS 
               de)x